# multiple screen support issues

Tags: android, multiscreen

I want to add multi screen layout support in my android project. For instance, now I am working with 1080x2280 and 1080x1920. I created a `layout-xxhdpi` folder and it is working for 1080x1920. But I'm facing problem with 1080x2280. It is taking the same `layout-xxhdpi`. How can i add separate layout support for this?

Comment: You're confusing screen **resolutions** and **densities**

Comment: Fantomas mi note 4x screen resulation is 1080*1920 mi note 6 pro screen resolution is 1080*2280

Comment: They have nearly the same **density**: `401ppi` the 4x and `403ppi` the 6pro. Therefore, they fall in the same (closest) dpi slot.

Comment: @Fantômas your  tagged ans don't contain solution of my problem.....so why  do you  my question is duplicate ??

Comment: You should follow the link in the comment. There's the answer to your problem - on the official android developers documentation.